# How do I prepare a Basal medium for autotrophic mutant creation

Tags: molecular-biology, microbiology

**Minimal medium (MM) was prepared by adding 2.0 g sodium nitrate (NaNO3) to 1 L of basal medium (BM) fol- lowing Correll et al. (1987). Chlorate resistant sectors (CRSs) were generated on two media i.e. MM and PDA containing 2.5% chlorate (KClO3), represented as MMC and PDC, respectively. The chlorate served as a toxic ana- logue of nitrite (Corell et al. 1987). Four phenotyping me- dia (Correll et al. 1987) were used i.e., i) sodium nitrate (NaNO3); ii) sodium nitrite (NaNO2), 0.5 g of NaNO2 was added to 1l BM; iii) hypoxanthine (HX-), 0.2 g of HX- was added to 1l BM; iv) ammonium tartrate (NH4+), 1.0 g NH4+ was added to 1l BM. MM was also used in pairing of the complementary nit mutants**

I’ve tried using the procedure on above but the minimal media is not solidifying

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Please do not present text as images. It discriminates against people with visual problems and is not indexable by the site. Type out as much as is necessary and provide a link to the source.

Comment: How do you expect the medium to solidify without adding any gelling substance like agar?

Comment: I added agar to it but it still did not gel